# Web server in DMZ subnet can't access internet through Ubuntu router with multiple NICs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server acting as a router with multiple NICs connected to different subnets. One of these subnets is a DMZ where my web server is located. The web server has a gateway set to 10.0.4.254, which is connected to the router. The router can ping the web server at 10.0.4.10, but the web server cannot ping the router or access the internet through it.

How can I troubleshoot this issue and allow my web server in the DMZ to access the internet through the Ubuntu router? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
You can find here screenshot of routing table of web-server and router/firewall machine and also a diagram of my infrastructure ( everything is up in virtualbox ).[Diagram-network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmrG9.jpg)
[Routing table web-serv & router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf2Cv.jpg)

I have already disabled UFW and iptables, but the issue persists. I tried using nmap, but it gives an error immediately stating that the host is not up.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post directly the text. In that picture one can see the server has two default routes. two default routes = something will fail. You might have to give additional information **as text formatted as code ** not as picture, from both systems: `ip link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule; ip neigh` as well as `nft list ruleset` and `sysctl -ar '\.rp_filter'`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.